# Simple Query using subsonic 2.2 with Oracle.dataclient error

Tags: sql, oracle, subsonic, ora-00923

I am using subsonic 2.2 with Oracle provider. I can use active record  but my simple query does not work!

```
int record = new Select(VenApplication.ApplicationidColumn).From(VenApplication)().GetRecordCount();
```

The error that I received is:

> ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Source Error:

> Line 23:             //int records = new Select(Product.ProductIDColumn, Product.ProductNameColumn).
>   Line 24:             //    From().GetRecordCount();
>   Line 25:             int record = new Select(VenApplication.ApplicationidColumn).From().GetRecordCount();
>   Line 26:             //int records = new Select(VenApplication.ApplicationidColumn).From().GetRecordCount();
>   Line 27:         }

Source File:

d:\myDoc2009\Visual Studio 2008\WebSites\UiaVendor\Default.aspx.cs    Line: 25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specifiy the table name,

```
Select(VenApplication.ApplicationidColumn).From(VenApplication).GetRecordCount();
```

Comment: my command is actually 
Select(VenApplication.ApplicationidColumn).From<VenApplication>.().GetRecordCount();

Comment: Well Try : Select(VenApplication.ApplicationidColumn).From(VenApplication).GetRecordCount();

Comment: Shouldn't the syntax be: Select(VenApplication.ApplicationidColumn).From(VenApplication.Schema).GetRecordCount();